# Tensorboard profile : No profile data was found

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard

## Problem

I dont see anything in the profile section in Tensorboard. I get the following Tensorboard interface after running `tensorboard --logdir logdir`

[image]

The tree of `logdir` is as follow:

```
logdir
├── events.out.tfevents.17026478. gpu.profile-empty
└── plugins
    └── profile
        ├── 2023_12_15_12_41_18
        │   ├──  gpu.input_pipeline.pb
        │   ├──  gpu.kernel_stats.pb
        │   ├──  gpu.memory_profile.json.gz
        │   ├──  gpu.overview_page.pb
        │   ├──  gpu.tensorflow_stats.pb
        │   ├──  gpu.trace.json.gz
        │   └──  gpu.xplane.pb
        ├── 2023_12_15_12_41_21
        │   ├──  gpu.input_pipeline.pb
        │   ├──  gpu.kernel_stats.pb
        │   ├──  gpu.memory_profile.json.gz
        │   ├──  gpu.overview_page.pb
        │   ├──  gpu.tensorflow_stats.pb
        │   ├──  gpu.trace.json.gz
        │   └──  gpu.xplane.pb
        ├── 2023_12_15_12_41_22
        │   ├──  gpu.input_pipeline.pb
        │   ├──  gpu.kernel_stats.pb
        │   ├──  gpu.memory_profile.json.gz
        │   ├──  gpu.overview_page.pb
        │   ├──  gpu.tensorflow_stats.pb
        │   ├──  gpu.trace.json.gz
        │   └──  gpu.xplane.pb
        ├── 2023_12_15_12_41_23
        │   ├──  gpu.input_pipeline.pb
        │   ├──  gpu.kernel_stats.pb
        │   ├──  gpu.memory_profile.json.gz
        │   ├──  gpu.overview_page.pb
        │   ├──  gpu.tensorflow_stats.pb
        │   ├──  gpu.trace.json.gz
        │   └──  gpu.xplane.pb
        ├── 2023_12_15_12_41_24
        │   ├──  gpu.input_pipeline.pb
        │   ├──  gpu.kernel_stats.pb
        │   ├──  gpu.memory_profile.json.gz
        │   ├──  gpu.overview_page.pb
        │   ├──  gpu.tensorflow_stats.pb
        │   ├──  gpu.trace.json.gz
        │   └──  gpu.xplane.pb
        ├── 2023_12_15_12_41_25
        │   ├──  gpu.input_pipeline.pb
        │   ├──  gpu.kernel_stats.pb
        │   ├──  gpu.memory_profile.json.gz
        │   ├──  gpu.overview_page.pb
        │   ├──  gpu.tensorflow_stats.pb
        │   ├──  gpu.trace.json.gz
        │   └──  gpu.xplane.pb
        └── 2023_12_15_12_41_26
            ├──  gpu.input_pipeline.pb
            ├──  gpu.kernel_stats.pb
            ├──  gpu.memory_profile.json.gz
            ├──  gpu.overview_page.pb
            ├──  gpu.tensorflow_stats.pb
            ├──  gpu.trace.json.gz
            └──  gpu.xplane.pb

9 directories, 50 files
```

## Code to generate `logdir`

This is a simple training loop using the `tf.profiler.experimental.Profile` API inspired from [this TF tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/simulations_with_accelerators) :

```
for epoch in range(1, epochs+1):                                                   
    
    if dataset_exists is True:
        #with tf.profiler.experimental.Trace('train', step_num=epoch, _r=1):       
        with tf.profiler.experimental.Profile("logdir"):
            loss_train = model.training_step(dataset, optimizer)                   
    else:
        loss_train = training_step(model._model, X_train, Y_train, optimizer)
```

## Additional information

I am running the code on a cluster in order to use a GPU. Then I use scp to copy the logdir folder from the cluster to my personal laptop.

Output of the command `tensorboard --logdir logdir --inspect`:

```
======================================================================
Processing event files... (this can take a few minutes)
======================================================================

Found event files in:
logdir

These tags are in logdir:
audio -
histograms -
images -
scalars -
tensor -
======================================================================

Event statistics for logdir:
audio -
graph -
histograms -
images -
scalars -
sessionlog:checkpoint -
sessionlog:start -
sessionlog:stop -
tensor -
=====================================================================
```

I can add the warnings in the terminal if necessary.

## Versions

- tensorboard==2.8.0
- tensorboard-data-server==0.6.1
- tensorboard-plugin-profile==2.15.0
- tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.1
- tensorflow==2.8.0
- tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.34.0

## Questions/Remarks

- By looking at [Tensorboard releases](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/releases), a user is supposed to use the same versions of Tensorflow and Tensorboard, since "Tensorboard version X tracks Tensorflow version X"
- For those who manage to use Tensorboard with Tensorflow, which versions of Tensorflow and Tensorboard did you use?

Comment: The following issue might be relevant: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/62373